# c# Newtonsoft DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind not working

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this code in my WebApiConfig file to serialize data:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Filters.Add(new DbValidationErrorAttribute());
        config.Filters.Add(new ValidationFailedErrorAttribute());
        config.Filters.Add(new GenericExceptionFilterAttribute());

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        var jSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat, 
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset, 
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind
        };

        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = jSettings;

        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator(jsonFormatter));
    }
```

It is a WebApi. The controller gets data from the frontend. My problem is with dates. They have a different timezone than the server timezone and they are converted to the server timezone. I tryed a lot of different options in JsonSerializerSettings. None of them worked. I also downloaded last newtonsoft version.

Any help to avoid timezone conversion?

Comment: Post examples of the generated strings. Do they contain an offset? Is the offset wrong? Are you ignoring the offset perhaps?  `10:00+00` is the same as `12:00+2:00` or `08:00-2:00`, there is no conversion involved

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  Are you using `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` in your class?  The former doesn't record time zone specifics, it only records a flag indicating whether the time is local, UTC or "unspecified".  `DateTimeOffset` actually records a time zone, see [Choosing Between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan, and TimeZoneInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).  And there's also [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) you could consider.

Comment: I am sending an object from angular frontend to my webapi backend controller. Some of the fields are DateTime in the backend, so the fields in my javascript frontend object are date objects. The problem is, let's say that the client is sending the date object from USA tike this: 12:00-5. And if the server is, let's say in Europe (GMT+2), I'll get in my controller 19:00+2. And this is my problem, I don't want to get a converted date. I want to get the same original date (12:00-5) the user sent.

Comment: @Acel - I don't think you can use `DateTime` on the backend then, it doesn't contain time zone information.  You have to use `DateTimeOffset as explained in [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).

Comment: None of the solutions are working for me. I have tryed everything and it is still not working. And I don't know what else can I do. I have tried to update the newtonsoft package, and also in the javascript sido I have added mydate.toISOString(). And finally my date in my api is a DateTimeOffSet type. But the offset property is always 0. What else can I do to know the original timezone date and time?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc`